# how to change the close button in the infowindow (bubble)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i want to customize the closebuttons in the info-windows (info-bubbles) on google maps using api v.3.
is there an easy way? meaning the api is providing this capability, or is there a good workaround out there.

thanks for help.

UPDATE

i have to add, that i want to change the style or at least the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [InfoBox](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/#svn/trunk/infowindow_custom) extention which is part of the [gmaps-samples-v3](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/) project on Google Code. That allows you to style the info window.